# Is there any R function to fulfill NA values with other values in the same column?

Tags: r

I want to convert the next dataframe:

```
>df1 

        A   B   C
    1   NA  NA  NA
    2   NA  NA  NA
    3   NA  NA  77
    4   NA  67  41
    5   20  28  65
    6   19  39  72
```

into:

```
>df1 

        A   B   C
    1   20  67  77
    2   19  28  41
    3   NA  39  65
    4   NA  NA  72
    5   NA  NA  NA
    6   NA  NA  NA
```

In other words, I would like to impute the NA values with the other values in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

We can reverse the `NA` elements

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
```

-output

```
df1
#   A  B  C
#1 20 67 77
#2 19 28 41
#3 NA 39 65
#4 NA NA 72
#5 NA NA NA
#6 NA NA NA
```

---

Or use `order` on the NA elements

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 20L, 19L), B = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 67L, 28L, 39L), C = c(NA, NA, 77L, 41L, 65L, 72L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```